# AWS IoT Core delete multiple things w/ single API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

you can delete one thing and one thing Group ... so on

```js
aws.iot().deleteThing({params}, callback);
```

but how to delete multiple things at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only API available is the one you mentioned, the deletion of a single Thing.

To delete multiple Things you can use a combination of [ListThings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_ListThings.html)/[SearchIndex](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_SearchIndex.html) APIs to first find the Things you want to delete and then call DeleteThing on each desired Thing.

[API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/Welcome.html)